# Wireless network scan

Tags: wireless, networking

I just installed with no problems Lubuntu on my Vaio pocket pc, wireless lan was detected and setup with fine from the beginning. I kept using my wireless connection to properly install updates, new programs, etc. Then I took my laptop to different place with available wireless network but I can find the way to connect to it. I have tried several programs and I still can not connect or scan any. Physical connection works fine and I'm using it to write this request.

```
uname -a

Linux carlos-VGN-P610T 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
$ iwconfig  

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

[sudo] password for carlos: 
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

My original network connection ("kiwi") used at the installation step:

```
ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Conexión inalámbrica 1  Kiwi
```

Could you please let me know some hints to solve this problem, I really need to use wireless connection when working on customer premises.

Comment: Try to install proprietary drivers for your wifi-card from setting menu.

Answer (score 0):

First, your network is down.

Make sure your wireless device button on your keyboard has not disabled the device. If that is okay, use . . .

**`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`**

to bring up the network device,

**`sudo service network-manager restart`**

to make sure network manager is running

and

**`sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 20`**

will make your wireless device reconnect more aggressively to a weak signal.

**Now**
You may know this but maybe don't so I'll be as detailed as I can.

On the lower right-hand side of the screen, to the left of the time display, there is an icon you can click on and this will bring up a menu with network settings to choose from.
Available wireless networks will show on this menu.

Click on the network you would like to connect to. If you should be prompted for a password. If there is no password you should automatically connect to the network.

You really shouldn't have to use too many commands to get network-manager to work as it's pretty good at doing it's job out of the box; just click on the icon. However, the default retry-long limit is only set to 7 to save power and sometimes needs to be increased (`sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 20`).

Hope I could help.